# Control flow in a program that transforms a number using base 10

Tags: c++, control-flow

Here is a program that does a number transformation and I am trying to understand the control flow of this code.

It's not really clear what the value of cn is in the first pass of the while loop, meaning if we declare cn = n at the beginning of the program, will the first value of cn be the first value of n  or it will be the value of n that is calculated in the first while loop, meaning n/=10.

Some hints would help...Thanks!

```
int n, cn, x=0,p=1;  

cin>>n;  

cn=n;  

while(n)  {   
    if (n%10>x) {x=n%10;}   
    n/=10;
} 

x++;  

while(cn)   {    
    n= n + cn%10 *p;   
    p*=x;    
    cn/=10;
}  

cout<<n;
```

Comment: `cn=n;` will copy the value of `n` into `cn`. `cn` won't depend on the value of `n` at all

Comment: Your question is a good example of why you should only declare variables until they can be initialized (see http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-init and http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es21-dont-introduce-a-variable-or-constant-before-you-need-to-use-it).

Comment: Thanks!!  It's actually really simple. Maybe not  all the time. Some things can be more complicated. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment statement of "**cn = n**" is

***temporarily assigning the value of n to cn***,

before n is going to get modified inside the while loop.

**Here is the program with print statements added to illustrate how the values are getting changed:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, cn, x = 0, p = 1;
    cout << "Enter the value of n: ";
    cin >> n;  

    cout << " n = " << n << " , cn = " << cn << "\n";
    cout << "Temporarily assigning the value of n to cn \n";

    cn = n;  
    cout << " n = " << n << " , cn = " << cn << "\n";

    while(n)  {   
        if ( n%10 > x ) {
            x = n%10;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }

    x++;

    cout << "Intermediate value of n = " << n << "\n";
    while( cn ) {
        n = n+cn%10*p;   
        p *= x;
        cn /= 10;
    }
    cout<<"Final value of n = " << n << "\n";
    return 1;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the value of n: 12345
 n = 12345 , cn = 0
Temporarily assigning the value of n to cn 
 n = 12345 , cn = 12345
Intermediate value of n = 0
Final value of n = 1865
```

The other question was,

***What will happen if cn=n is used in the first statement of the program ?***

I.E.,

```
int n, cn=n, x = 0, p = 1;
```

**Answer:**  This will assign a random value to cn.

Here is a demo of what would be done by the ***int n, cn=n*** statement:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, cn=n, x = 0, p = 1;
    cout << "Enter the value of n: ";
    cin >> n;  

    cout << " n = " << n << " , cn = " << cn << "\n";

    while(n)  {   
        if ( n%10 > x ) {
            x = n%10;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }

    x++;

    cout << "Intermediate value of n = " << n << "\n";
    while( cn ) {
        n = n+cn%10*p;   
        p *= x;
        cn /= 10;
    }
    cout<<"Final value of n = " << n << "\n";
    return 1;
}
```

**Output of int n, cn=n :**

```
Enter the value of n: 12345
 n = 12345 , cn = 4196992
Intermediate value of n = 0
Final value of n = 207740
```

Comment: Thanks!! Now I understand everything. This definitely made all the solutions very clear. I really appreciate your help.Thanks again!!